# Difference between writing to partition path directly and using partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark

Are there any differences between:

```
df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").parquet("/my/path/on/hdfs")
```

and

```
df.drop("year", "month", "day").write.parquet("/my/path/on/hdfs/year=2019/month=8/day=12")
```

(when I know the values of year, month and day as (2019/8/12))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Approach 1. df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").parquet("/my/path/on/hdfs")

Approach 2. df.drop("year", "month", "day").write.parquet("/my/path/on/hdfs/year=2019/month=8/day=12")
```

There can be difference between these two statements depending on SaveMode.

By default SaveMode is `ErrorIfExists`. So if you have a some data at `/my/path/on/hdfs`, although you might not have any data on `/my/path/on/hdfs/year=2019/month=8/day=12`, then Approach_1 will fail and Approach_2 will work.

If SaveMode `Overwrite`, then Approach_1 will delete all data present in  `/my/path/on/hdfs` and only new data will be created inside  `/my/path/on/hdfs/year=2019/month=8/day=12`. But Approach_2 won't delete other partitions data inside `/my/path/on/hdfs/`.

Comment: my SaveMode is `Overwrite` and Approach 2 is what I want to move to.